# TFS Test Filter Criteria syntax

Tags: testing, tfs, automated-tests, nunit, tfsbuild

I am struggling with excluding tests in automated TFS run.

In settings for Test filter criteria gave but the it doesn't seem to exclude the tests in that category
($(TestFilter))&(TestCategory!~)
Also tried ($(TestFilter))&(TestCategory!=)

Any suggestions or examples on how to use the filter queries?

TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> TFS Test Filter Criteria syntax

To exclude the tests in that category, you could set following test category filters in the VS test task:

```
TestCategory!=Manual
```

[image]

For more details about filtering pleace take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md)

Comment: Thanks, this works for excluding one TestCategory but I want the class has multiple categories across different namespaces, so trying to figure out how to create that kind of query. e.g. one namespace XYZ has TestCategory "A" and "B" and another namespace has TestCategory "A" too and another class in XYZ namespace doesn't have any TestCategory.